# Quotients of abelian groups - residual finiteness and elements of order $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Suppose $A$ is an abelian group and $\pi$ is a set of prime numbers. A $\pi$-number is a product of primes from $\pi$.

Assume that for each $p \in \pi$, $A_p = \{a \in A : \exists i\in\mathbb{N} \text{ s.t } a^{p^i} = 0\}$ has finite exponent.

Assume also that $A$ is $\pi$-reduced; there are no non-trivial subgroups of $A$ which are $\pi$-divisible. That is, for any $H \leq A$ there is $h \in H$ and $m$ a $\pi$-number such that for any $x \in H$, $x^m \neq h$.

Let $j \in \mathbb{N}$, $p \in \pi$ and $m = p^jn$ a $\pi$-number where $n$ is relatively prime to $p$.

1. why is $A/A^m$ residually finite?
2. why does $A^{p^j}/A^m$ have no element of order $p$?

Here is the context from Infinite Soluble Groups:

[image]

Comment: @halrankard thanks, edited. I edited the second question and took it off for a few minutes.

Comment: Ok I see, it makes sense now. I'll delete the previous comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A/A^m$ is an abelian group of finite exponent (specifically, exponent dividing $m$), and every abelian group of finite exponent is a direct sum of cyclic groups and in particular residually finite.  See for instance the answers at [infinite abelian group where all elements have order 1, 2, or 4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2394815/infinite-abelian-group-where-all-elements-have-order-1-2-or-4).

Since every element $a\in A/A^m$ satisfies $a^m=1$, every $p^j$th power $a^{p^j}$ satisfies $(a^{p^j})^n=1$.  Thus the order of $a^{p^j}$ divides $n$, and so cannot be $p$.  That is, $A^{p^j}/A^m$ has no elements of order $p$.

Comment: Thanks for that reference! The second question, I don't know why it confused me..